# Find all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $2014^x+11^x=y^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that
$$2014^x+11^x=y^2$$
In my book it says that only solution is $(x,y)=(1,45)$, but solution is very complicated. They proved that $(x,y)=(1,45)$ is only solution using remainders of division, but I think that there must be an easier way. How would you solve this? What is the easiest way to solve equations like this?

Comment: "Using remainders of division" -- in other words modular arithmetic -- is a straightforward and ubiquitous technique in elementary number theory. You probably won't find many arguments that are "easier" than that.

Comment: To echo Henning's comment: Diophantine equations are frequently extremely hard to solve, and require techniques much harder than modular arithmetic.  I doubt very much that there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: In fact, even polynomial equations can be unsolveable. Here it is worse because $x$ appears in the exponent. There is no general method to solve such equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is 'using remainders of division', but I don't think it's very complicated.

**Working $\mod 3$:**

Recall that any square number is either $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$.  This can easily be checked by squaring each of the three possible residues $\mod 3$ and seeing that you only ever get $0$ or $1$.  Now:

\begin{align}
2014&\equiv 1&\mod 3\\
11&\equiv-1&\mod 3
\end{align}

So our equation
$$
2014^x+11^x=y^2
$$
gives us that
$$
1+(-1)^x\in\{0,1\}\mod 3
$$
If $x$ is even, then $1+(-1)^x\equiv 2$, so $x$ must be odd.

**Working $\mod 4$:**

Recall that any square number is either $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.  Once again, this is easy to check by squaring the four possible residues $\mod 4$ and checking that you always get either $0$ or $1$.  We have:

\begin{align}
2014&\equiv 2&\mod 4\\
11&\equiv-1&\mod 4
\end{align}

So our equation
$$
2014^x+11^x=y^2
$$
gives us that
$$
2^x+(-1)^x\in\{0,1\}\mod 4
$$

Since $x$ is odd, $(-1)^x\equiv -1$, so we have:
$$
2^x-1\in\{0,1\}\mod 4
$$
If $x>1$, then $2^x\equiv0$, so $2^x-1\equiv -1$.  Therefore, we must have $x=1$.  Computation tells us that $2014^1+11^1=45^2$, so we have a unique solution $(1,45)$.